# How to force restart AppStore when new app update

Tags: xcode, app-store

I got an app with popup about new app update. The problem is that the app is blocked by our popup and when you click update, you get into App Store, there is only option "open" there. If you close App Store and reopen, it does refresh and finds "update". Is it possible to force refresh AppStore somehow or any quite solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a good library available for this purpose. [Library](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy)

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Perform daily check for new version of your app
    [[Harpy sharedInstance] checkVersionDaily];
}
```

[Original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768193/7956211)

Comment: Man, I don't need solution for alert. When I click my button - it finds appstore application, but there are no "update" button till I restart AppStore

Comment: Programmatically restarting app-store is not possible. I never faced the issue which you are facing with the library mentioned in answer.